# Bash script to join two csv files by a similar field and output to third field

Tags: linux, bash, csv, join, merge

I have 2 csv files.  file1.csv and file2.csv  with the following field names

file1.csv:
user_id, email

file2.csv:
user_id, first_name, second_name

I created a bash script to merge the two csv files:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Script to merge two csv files based on user_id


join --header -t, <(sort -t, -k1 file_a.csv) <(sort -t, -k1 file_b.csv) > file3.csv
```

The only issue is that the output puts the column names user_id, email, first_name, last_name 3 rows from the bottom mixed in with the data.  Anyone have an idea how I should correct this in order to get the field names back to the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your sort is mixing up header with data, unfortunately sort doesn't have a *ignore header* option. Here `awk` comes to the rescue!

First define a function

```
$ function sorth() { awk 'NR==1; NR>1{print | "sort"}' "$1"; }
```

now you can

```
$ join --header -t, <(sorth file1) <(sorth file2)
```

**N.B.** I don't think sorting with `-k1` is adding any value here, but perhaps different in your locale.  If so, add the options in the `awk` script.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply write:

```
join --header -t, <(
    { read;echo $REPLY;sort -t, -k1;}<file_a.csv
  ) <(
    { read;echo $REPLY;sort -t, -k1;}<file_b.csv
  ) > outputfile.csv
```

Or you could create a function:

```
hsort() {
    {
        read
        echo $REPLY
        sort -t, -k1
    } < "$1"
}
```

Then

```
join --header -t, <(hsort file_a.csv) <(hsort file_b.csv) >outputfile.csv
```